CloudKit crash in recordMatchBlock
This query is crashing sometimes and not others with;
Object 0x11f825800 of class _ContiguousArrayStorage deallocated with non-zero retain count 2. This object's deinit, or something called from it, may have created a strong reference to self which outlived deinit, resulting in a dangling reference.
On crash the record and array both display as usual. The array is declared inside the class. No other CloudKit calls are running.
  queryOperation.queuePriority = .veryHigh
  queryOperation.resultsLimit = 399 

 queryOperation.recordMatchedBlock =
    {
        id, result in
        switch result
        {
        case .success(let record) :
            self.sampleSet.append(record) <--- CRASH HERE
        case .failure(let error):
               print("record matched error = \(error.localizedDescription).")
        }
    }
  
    queryOperation.queryResultBlock =
    {
        result in          
        switch result
        {
        case .success(let cursor) :
            if cursor != nil
            {
                recurrentOperations(cursor: cursor!)
            }
            else
            {
                self.loadedSet = true
                completion(nil) 
            }
           
        case .failure(let error):
                self.loadStatus = "load failed"
                completion(error)
        }
    }
   
    privateDB.add(queryOperation) // start the query

